# Using " contains " in kotlin for provide if the input have contains english letters

Tags: java, kotlin

how can I use " contains "?
if the input have contains english letters it's always shows me false even if am write a english letter small/capital

```
 val eLang: String = ("aA b   B c   C d   D e   E f   F g   G h   H i   I j   J k   K l   L m   M n   N o   O p   P q   Q r   R s   S t   T u   U v   V w   W x   X y   Y z   Z")
```

output : false

```
       println( input_string?.contains(eLang, ignoreCase = true))
```

main code

```
class Loop {

    public val input_string: String? = readLine().toString()
    public val input_size = readLine()?.toInt()

    fun looping(a: String, b: Int) {
        val eLang: String = ("aA b   B c   C d   D e   E f   F g   G h   H i   I j   J k   K l   L m   M n   N o   O p   P q   Q r   R s   S t   T u   U v   V w   W x   X y   Y z   Z")
        if ((input_size!! > 1) && input_string != "") {
            for (i in 0 until input_size) {

                println(input_string)
            }

            input_string?.let { println("length word you type : ${it.length}") }
            input_size?.let { println("Count looping: ${(input_size)}") }

           println( input_string?.contains(eLang, ignoreCase = true))



        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You want to know if an input `String` contains one or more English alphabet characters? Because what you're doing right now is testing if `input_string` has any _substring_ that _equals_ `eLang` (ignoring case).

Comment: right i want if at least one Char from eLang ,, i just type the hole alphabet characters on the input and gives me a " true " but when i only type " a " "a b c " gives me false

Comment: Try something like `input_string.any { it in eLang }` or, if you need to ignore case, `input_string.any { eLang.contains(it, ignoreCase = true) }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if an input has any letters, simply do

> val hasALetter = input.any(Char::isLetter)

What you're doing is checking if the input has the entire alphabet string, which is not what you want to be doing.